# Как сохранить информацию после закрытия приложения в PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyqt, mediaplayer

1. При запуске приложения выдает ошибку:

```
DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource: Unresolved error code 0x80070005 (???????? ? ???????.)
```

В интернете не нашел никакой информации по поводу этой ошибки

2. Как сделать функцию сохранения файлов в ListWidget после закрытия приложения?

**AudioPlayer.py**

```
class AudioPlayer(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(AudioPlayer, self).__init__(parent, flags = QtCore.Qt.Window | QtCore.Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window)
        self.setWindowTitle("Audio Player")

        self.mplPlayer = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.mplPlayer.setVolume(50)
        self.mplPlayer.mediaStatusChanged.connect(self.init_player)
        self.mplPlayer.stateChanged.connect(self.set_player_state)

        self.playlist = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlaylist()

        self.list_widget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.list_widget.doubleClicked.connect(self.list_play_func)

        files = [""]

        for f in files:
            self.playlist.addMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(f))) # +
            self.playlist.setPlaybackMode(QtMultimedia.QMediaPlaylist.Loop)                      # + 
            self.list_widget.addItems([m.split('/')[-1] for m in files]) 

        fn = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.abspath(files[0]))
        self.playlist.insertMedia(4, QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(fn))
        self.playlist.removeMedia(0)
        self.playlist.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.mplPlayer.setPlaylist(self.playlist)   

        vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        button_open = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Open file")
        button_open.clicked.connect(self.open_file)

        image_night_city = QtGui.QPixmap("night_city.jpg").scaled(300, 300)

        label_night_city = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        label_night_city.setPixmap(image_night_city)
        label_night_city.setFrameStyle(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box | QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        label_night_city.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        vlayout.addStretch(1)
        vlayout.addWidget(button_open)
        vlayout.addStretch(1)
        vlayout.addWidget(label_night_city)
        vlayout.addStretch(1)

        self.sldPosition = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.sldPosition.setMinimum(0)     
        self.sldPosition.sliderMoved[int].connect(self.setPlayPosition) 

        self.mplPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.sldPosition.setValue)
        self.mplPlayer.durationChanged.connect(self.get_duration_func)

        self.sldPosition.setEnabled(False)

        vlayout.addWidget(self.sldPosition)

        hlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        font1 = QtGui.QFont()
        font1.setPixelSize(15)
        font_play = QtGui.QFont()
        font_play.setPixelSize(30)
        self.button_next = QtWidgets.QPushButton("⏯")
        self.button_previous = QtWidgets.QPushButton("⏮")
        self.button_shuffle = QtWidgets.QPushButton("")
        self.button_next.clicked.connect(self.playlist.next)
        self.button_next.setFixedSize(70, 30)
        self.button_previous.clicked.connect(self.playlist.previous)
        self.button_previous.setFixedSize(70, 30)
        self.button_shuffle.clicked.connect(self.playlist.shuffle)
        self.button_shuffle.setFixedSize(70, 30)
        self.button_play = QtWidgets.QPushButton(" ▶ ")
        self.button_play.setFixedSize(70, 30)
        self.button_play.clicked.connect(self.mplPlayer.play)
        self.button_play.setEnabled(False)

        self.button_pause = QtWidgets.QPushButton("||")
        self.button_pause.setFixedSize(70, 30)
        self.button_pause.clicked.connect(self.mplPlayer.pause)
        self.button_pause.setEnabled(False)

        self.button_stop = QtWidgets.QPushButton("⏹")
        self.button_stop.setFixedSize(70, 30)
        self.button_stop.clicked.connect(self.mplPlayer.stop)
        self.button_stop.setEnabled(False)

        self.button_play.setFont(font_play)
        self.button_pause.setFont(font1)
        self.button_stop.setFont(font1)
        self.button_next.setFont(font1)
        self.button_previous.setFont(font1)
        self.button_shuffle.setFont(font1)

        horizontal_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        horizontal_layout.addWidget(self.button_previous)
        horizontal_layout.addWidget(self.button_play)
        horizontal_layout.addWidget(self.button_pause)
        horizontal_layout.addWidget(self.button_stop)
        horizontal_layout.addWidget(self.button_next)
        horizontal_layout.addWidget(self.button_shuffle)

        button_mute = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Mute")
        button_mute.setCheckable(True)
        button_mute.toggled.connect(self.mplPlayer.setMuted)
        hlayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        vlayout.addStretch(1)
        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout)
        vlayout.addStretch(1)
        vlayout.addLayout(horizontal_layout)
        vlayout.addStretch(1)

        hlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        label_volume = QtWidgets.QLabel("&Volume")

        vlayout.addStretch(1)
        hlayout.addWidget(label_volume)
        vlayout.addStretch(1)


        slider_volume = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        slider_volume.setRange(0, 100)
        slider_volume.setTickPosition(QtWidgets.QSlider.TicksAbove)
        slider_volume.setTickInterval(10)
        slider_volume.setValue(10)

        label_volume.setBuddy(slider_volume)

        vlayout.addStretch(1)
        hlayout.addWidget(slider_volume)
        vlayout.addStretch(1)

        self.button_mute = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Mute")
        self.button_mute.setCheckable(True)
        self.button_mute.toggled.connect(self.mplPlayer.setMuted)

        vlayout.addStretch(1)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.button_mute)
        vlayout.addStretch(1)

        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout)

        self.label_current = QtWidgets.QLabel("")

        vlayout.addStretch(1)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.label_current)
        vlayout.addStretch(1)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.list_widget)
        vlayout.addStretch(1)

        self.playlist.currentMediaChanged.connect(self.show_File)

        self.setLayout(vlayout)
        self.resize(300, 100)

    def open_file(self):
        file, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self,
            "Add sound",
            "",
            "Sound Filed(*.mp3 *.ac3 *.wav)"
        )
        if not file:
            return
        self.playlist.addMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(file)))
        self.list_widget.addItem(file.split('/')[-1])

    def show_File(self, content):
        self.label_current.setText(content.canonicalUrl().fileName())

    def list_play_func(self):
        self.mplPlayer.stop()
        self.playlist.setCurrentIndex(self.list_widget.currentRow())
        self.mplPlayer.play()

    def get_duration_func(self, d):
        self.sldPosition.setRange(0, d)

    def init_player(self, state):
        if state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.LoadedMedia:
            self.mplPlayer.stop()
            self.button_play.setEnabled(True)
            self.sldPosition.setEnabled(True)
            self.sldPosition.setMaximum(self.mplPlayer.duration())

        elif state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.NoMedia or state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.InvalidMedia:
            self.sldPosition.setValue(0)
            self.sldPosition.setEnabled(False)
            self.button_play.setEnabled(False)
            self.button_stop.setEnabled(False)
            self.button_pause.setEnabled(False)

    def set_player_state(self, state):
        if state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.StoppedState:
            self.sldPosition.setValue(0)
            self.button_pause.setEnabled(False)
            self.button_stop.setEnabled(False)

        elif state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.button_pause.setEnabled(True)
            self.button_stop.setEnabled(True)

        elif state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.PausedState:
            self.button_pause.setEnabled(False)
            self.button_stop.setEnabled(True)

    def setPlayPosition(self, value):
         self.mplPlayer.setPosition(value)
```

**Player.py**

```
class Player (QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Player, self).__init__(parent)

        if os.path.exists('music.ini'):
            with open('music.ini', 'r') as f:
                self.music = f.read()
        else:
            with open('music.ini', 'w') as f:
                self.music = 0


        background = QtGui.QImage("lion.jpg").scaled(600, 600)

        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(10, QtGui.QBrush(background))

        self.setPalette(palette)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window)

        button_audio_player = QtWidgets.QPushButton("АУДИО ПЛЕЕР")
        button_video_player = QtWidgets.QPushButton("ВИДЕО ПЛЕЕР")

        button_audio_player.setFixedSize(450, 70)
        button_video_player.setFixedSize(450, 70)

        font = QtGui.QFont("Comfortaa", 20, QtGui.QFont.Bold)

        button_audio_player.setStyleSheet("""
        QPushButton{
            background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 20%);
            color: #FFFFFF;
            border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
            margin: 50px;
        }
        """)

        button_video_player.setStyleSheet("""
        QPushButton{
            background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 20%);
            color: #FFFFFF;
            border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
            margin: 50px;
        }
        """)

        shadow = QtWidgets.QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self,
            blurRadius=14.0,                   
            color=QtGui.QColor("#FF0000"),
            offset=QtCore.QPointF(0.0, 0.0)  
        )

        button_audio_player.setGraphicsEffect(shadow)
        button_video_player.setGraphicsEffect(shadow)

        button_audio_player.setFont(font)
        button_video_player.setFont(font)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addStretch(1)
        layout.addWidget(button_audio_player)
        layout.addStretch(1)
        layout.addWidget(button_video_player)
        layout.addStretch(1)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        button_audio_player.clicked.connect(self.open_audio_player)
        button_video_player.clicked.connect(self.open_video_player)

    def open_audio_player(self):
        self.window = AudioPlayer(self)
        self.window.setWindowTitle("Audio Player")
        self.window.resize(300, 300)
        self.window.show()

    def open_video_player(self):
        self.window = VideoPlayer(self)
        self.window.setWindowTitle("Video Player")
        self.window.resize(600, 600)
        self.window.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка `DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource: Unresolved error code...` в общем случае означает, что система не может распознать путь к медиа-данным, а дальше уже нюансы:

- Например, для виндовс путь задан с прямыми слешами `\`. В этом случае их надо поменять на обратные `/`. Двойные `\\` менять, конечно, не надо
- Путь задан, например, так `file://path/2/filename.ext`. Здесь должно быть `file:///...`
- Нередко бывает так, что система (не Qt, а именно подлежащая система) не может распознать формат медиа-данных: неизвестный контейнер (формат), нет нужного кодека, фильтра,  тому подобное. Простое решение, это установить соответствующие кодеки. Бывает, что версия вашего Qt подхватывает устаревшие функции платформы, которые неспособны распознать ресурсы. Либо обратная ситуация, версия Qt настолько новая, что она хватает сырые функции системных библиотек, хотя бывает, что других и нет. В таком случае надо изменить версию Qt, либо обновить систему и соответствующие библиотеки.

Не забывайте, что в общем виде эта ошибка означает, что система не может прочесть/распознать путь к файлу, включая сам файл.

Второе. Сохранить содержимое `QListWidget` можно при помощи класса [`QSettings`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QSettings.html).

Считываете ваши данные из QListWidget и формируете список строк:

```
# Сохранение
# Список строк из QListWidget
playlist = []
...
settings = QSettings('media.list', QSettings.IniFormat)
settings.setValue('playlist_#1', playlist)
# Сохранение в файл
settings.sync()

# Чтение
settings = QSettings('media.list', QSettings.IniFormat)
# Второй параметр это значение по-умолчанию, если такой записи в 
# в файле еще нет
r = settings.value('playlist_#1', None)
if r:
    playlist = r.toList()

# Добавляем данные из playlist в QListWidget и QMediaPlayer
...
```

Дополнение. Получение данных из QMediaPlaylist:

```
playlist = []
mediaList = QMediaPlayList()
for index in range(mediaList.mediaCount()):
    content = mediaList.media(index)
    playlist.append(content.canonicalUrl().url())
```

Comment: ```File "FinalCode.py", line 570, in __init__
    self.playlist = settings.value('play_list_#1').toList()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'toList'```

Comment: + у меня плейлист не просто массив а ```QMediaPlaylist```

Comment: @Lcashe Значит не существует `play_list_#1` это надо проверять

Comment: @Lcashe QMediaPlaylist  состоит из QMediaContent, который состоит из QUrl, который состоит из QString (путей к медиа-файлам). Вам надо сохранять в ини-файл строки, а при чтении формировать QUrl->QMediaContent и QMediaPlaylist

Comment: откуда взялся playlist_#1 и play_list_#1?

Comment: @Lcashe это просто имя группы (ключ), по которому мы храним и получаем данные (список путей). Вы можете использовать любое на ваше усмотрение. Для каждого плейлиста вы можете создать свое имя, то есть playlist_#1, playlist_#2, playlist_#3 и так далее

Comment: @Lcashe обновил  settings.value(...)

Comment: Снова ошибка:

```QVariant::load: unable to load type 39.
QVariant::save: unable to save type 'QObject*' (type id: 39).

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FinalCode.py", line 918, in open_audio_player
    self.window = AudioPlayer(self)
  File "FinalCode.py", line 574, in __init__
    self.playlist = r.toList()
AttributeError: 'QMediaPlaylist' object has no attribute 'toList'```

Comment: @Lcashe а что вы пытаетесь сделать? У QMediaPlaylist действительно нет метода toList(). Я добавил в ответ как это можно сделать

Comment: не знаю работает или нет потому что не смог решить проблему с первой ошибкой. у меня музыкальные файлы находятся в папке с .py кодом, и я не указывал путь к файлам (взял обновленный вариант)